# Automatically updating a mac app

Tags: macos

I am working on a desktop app in Qt that would work on Windows and Mac,

I have to add a features in the app to check for updates and apply them to the software 
I have already done it one windows (on windows download updates dlls/exe files remove existing and put new ones there )

I am not much familiar with deployments/install on mac on windows I just update the files in my install directory.

To do similar in mac do I have to consider special deployment strategy to auto update the software ? like do I need to make an installer for mac or do I bundle it ? essentially I want to be able to auto update the software whichever strategy allows me to do that..

May be its important that the app is not going in mac store rather the users would download it from a website..

Please advise,

Thanks,

Comment: This question got the answer to this problem.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22012901/how-to-upgrade-mac-osx-application

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without the App Store, the next most common solution I've seen is the Sparkle framework:

http://sparkle.andymatuschak.org/