# How to upgrade Mac OSX Application

Tags: macos, auto-update

I'm working on client side. We have a daemon running which checks for new version availability on server and whenever it's available it downloads the new .dmg file.

Now I wanted to upgrade the existing application silently without showing the installation window.

I wanted to know what are the ways to auto upgrade any mac osx application.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but any particular reason not to use the Store which has this functionality by default?

Comment: I'm working on an enterprise application which is not available in AppStore. This application will be installed on client machines by the Administrator. Now, whenever a new version is available we wanted to auto upgrade the client app.

Comment: Have you seen [Sparkle](http://sparkle.andymatuschak.org)? It might do what you need.

Comment: Thanks. I just got the reference of it from other stackoverflow que.

Comment: How is the application packaged? I.e. what's inside the .dmg file, a .pkg package, the raw .app bundle, etc?

Comment: It contains .pkg file along with application specific files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sparkle does couple of things internally

1. It checks for the new version available on server or not.
2. If it's available then download it and upgrade the existing app and
   relaunch the same application.

I'm more of interested in 2nd part, so here is how it does it.

```
NSString *installerPath = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] absolutePathForAppBundleWithIdentifier:@"com.apple.installer"];
    installerPath = [installerPath stringByAppendingString:@"/Contents/MacOS/Installer"];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:installerPath])
    {
        error = [NSError errorWithDomain:SUSparkleErrorDomain code:SUMissingInstallerToolError userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Couldn't find Apple's installer tool!" forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey]];
        result = NO;
    }
    NSTask *installer = [NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:installerPath arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:path, nil]];
    [installer waitUntilExit];
```

Now here you can see that it finds the Installer.app and pass the pkg as command line argument to it.

Installer app takes care of upgrading the app.

There is one more way of doing it silently using terminal command line executable `/usr/sbin/installer` - More information is on wiki - [Installer(Mac OS X)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Installer_%28OS_X%29)

If you do not want to launch the Installer GUI then you can use above command and give pkg file path and volume information for installation.

Here are samples.

```
installer -pkg InstallMe.pkg -target CurrentUserHomeDirectory
installer -pkg InstallMe.pkg -target '/Volumes/Macintosh HD2' -lang ja
installer -volinfo -pkg InstallMe.pkg
installer -pkginfo -pkg InstallMe.pkg
installer -query RestartAction -pkg InstallMe.pkg
installer -pkg InstallMe.pkg -target / -showChoices
```